# Law of iterated expectations given inequality

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables and let $z$ be a constant. Is the following true:

$E\Bigr[E[X|Y]\Bigl| Y>z] = E[X| Y>z]$

I think it is true by the Law of Iterated Expectations. Is this correct? If not, is the statement true due to some other property or is it false in general?

Comment: Were you able to transform the answer below into a full proof? You might wish to show how...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I wasn't able.

Comment: I was under the impression that the proof in the answer was correct. The question wasn't getting any attention, so I had to move on.

Comment: It seems that some users got the impression that my previous comment, asking the OP why they had accepted a post they did not understand (and which happens to fail to address their question), was offending in one way or another, and that the site was better off if said comment was deleted... Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is true

Let $X$ and $Y$ be defined on $\Omega$ and let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ be our probability space. If $\mathcal D\subseteq \mathcal E$ are sub $\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal F$ then 
$$
E[X\mid \mathcal D] = E\bigl[E[X\mid \mathcal E]\mid \mathcal D\bigr] = E\bigl[E[X\mid\mathcal D]\mid \mathcal E\bigr],
$$
which we call the law of the iterated expectation.

Note that $\{Y>z\} \subseteq \{Y\in \mathbb R\}$ and recall that what we mean by $E[X\mid Y]$ is the expectation of $X$ given the $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$, so you are fine.

Comment: $\{Y>z\}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra though.

Comment: The indication to [Note that $\{Y>z\} \subseteq \{Y\in \mathbb R\}$] is useless and, more annoyingly, quite misleading. All in all, I fail to see a proof of the answer here and I would not know how to apply the law of the iterated expectation...